# How to show perspective view text without any distortion

Tags: adobe-photoshop, perspective

I am working on a design in which i want to show a snippet of code of html on a page which is skewed, but when I adjust the text according to that it's distorted and does not look like the part of the page.

This is what I have so far:
 [image]

Comment: Why aren't you simply distorting the paper and text at the same time rather than separately? I'd lay the text on the paper flat, group them, then distort to ensure they remain in the same distortion together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing wrong, That's why its not going the way you want to. you have to group/link both to get the desired effect

**What you have to do is :**

- You have to write your code in your layer which you want to skew.
- After that link both text(you can rasterize text layer its not necessary when using skew) and background layer (select both layer and press link icon, highlighted in screenshot)
- then `ctrl+t` and what ever you want to do select the same option by clicking `right mouse click`
- then do whatever you want to do, I guess it's simple and easy. my output is not similar to you, I have used perspective, but the technique will lead you to the same.

I am attaching some quick/ugly screenshots to make this clear to you hope they'll help

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well you have two problems with persepctive. One is that your 'paper' is not in perspective. The other is that you didn't make your code match the paper.... or be in perspective.

See to put your paper in perspective using what you've already done you should still have two sides be parallel which you don't. Here is what I mean - you should have either the blue area filled or the green area filled based on your current lines. The blue could be made a bit wider, I was doing this fast but its very foreshortened with that angle you currently have (top of your existing piece) so the green would be a better perspective since you want to see the top of the paper with the code on it:

[image: Perspective Lines]

Then you need to distort your text more so that it is the same using that distory tool. By definition YOU ARE going to distort the text, perspective function alone in photoshop isn't really going to cut it for what you want to achieve.

What you might try doing is making a black 'box' to act as the paper and write your text on it. Then group those layers together and distort them at the same time.

Comment: Can you show an example

Comment: Look at the picture above. See the area that looks like a green trapezoid? That's where your content needs to be to be in perspective. That is an example.

Comment: Actually, those lines don't have to be parallel like that. Both sets of lines can be extending towards a vanishing point. However, the vanishing point (narrower end) should always be pointed away from the viewer. In this case, the second vanishing point is illogically placed and so the wedge shape doesn't make sense spacially, and neither do the shadows.